# How to select a Radio button in Watir with label text?

Tags: ruby, radio-button, watir

The cheatsheets and docs on Watir show something like this to set a radio button

```
b.radio(:id => "radio").set
```

How can I select a Radio button *based on the text next to it*?

Sometimes this text is inside the label tag , sometimes its just inside some div/form tag. How do we handle this in Watir??

*(Label texts in CAPS in below examples)*

**Example 1:**

```
<form action="">
<input type="radio" value="male" name="sex"/>
MALE
<br/>
<input type="radio" value="female" name="sex"/>
FEMALE
</form>
```

**Example 2 :**

```
<div class="isoversixteen_false_container">
<input id="isoversixteen_false" class="radio" type="radio" value="0" name="isoversixteen" autocomplete="off"/>
<label class="isoversixteen_false_label" for="isoversixteen_false">
<span class="label_main">UNDER 16</span>
</label>
</div>
<div class="isoversixteen_true_container">
<input id="isoversixteen_true" class="radio" type="radio" value="1" name="isoversixteen" autocomplete="off" checked="checked"/>
<label class="isoversixteen_true_label" for="isoversixteen_true">
<span class="label_main">16 OR OVER</span>
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: You have unique `value` attributes in Example #1, so you could do `b.radio(:value => "male").set`.  In example #2, there are unique `id` attributes, so something like `b.radio(:id => "isoversixteen_true").set` should work.  Is there a reason that you want to use the text as a locator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orde's comment about using attributes of the input element is a good idea as it is the easiest to program. However, to answer the question:

**Example 1 - Adjacent text node**

In this example, the desired text is in an adjacent text node. Given that the radio buttons share the same parent, I think the easiest solution would be to use XPath:

```
browser.radio(xpath: '//input[following-sibling::text()[1][normalize-space(.) = "MALE"]]').set
browser.radio(xpath: '//input[following-sibling::text()[1][normalize-space(.) = "FEMALE"]]').set
```

The XPath says to:

1. Find an input element where
2. The following text node - ie the `[1]`
3. Has the text "MALE" or "FEMALE", ignoring the leading/following spaces - ie the `[normalize-space(.) = "FEMALE"]`

**Example 2 - Label text**

In this example, the checkboxes have a properly associated label element - ie the id of the checkbox matches the for attribute of the label. Watir supports locating elements by their label text through the `:label` locator:

```
browser.radio(label: 'UNDER 16').set
browser.radio(label: '16 OR OVER').set
```

**Example - First following non-blank text node**

If you want a single solution that works with both examples, the following seems to work:

```
browser.radio(xpath: '//input[following::text()[normalize-space(.) != ""][1][normalize-space(.) = "UNDER 16"]]').set
browser.radio(xpath: '//input[following::text()[normalize-space(.) != ""][1][normalize-space(.) = "16 OR OVER"]]').set
browser.radio(xpath: '//input[following::text()[normalize-space(.) != ""][1][normalize-space(.) = "MALE"]]').set
browser.radio(xpath: '//input[following::text()[normalize-space(.) != ""][1][normalize-space(.) = "FEMALE"]]').set
```

The intent here is to find the first text node after the checkbox that has text (the `[normalize-space(.) != ""][1]` portion) and that text matches the expected text (the `[normalize-space(.) = "UNDER 16"` portion).

Comment: Hi @Justin , Thanks a lot for the answer. I'll try out both ways. I was wondering can we have a generalized way of doing this? Because I'm writing a wrapper on the set method of watir, which will just take label text and set that radio button :).

Comment: It seems that you can make a single XPath that works for both examples (see updated answer). I have not had to do this XPath before so I am not sure where the limitations/risks are.

Comment: Wonderful!! I had implemented your answer before the update using a conditional loop, now if this works,nothing better :)

Answer (score 2):

This is HTML structure I have in my example:

```
<div class="radio-inline">
<label for="job_type">Second Type</label>
<input id="job_service" name="job" type="radio" value="remote">
</div>
```

Normally I'd select it with:

```
@browser.input(:value => 'remote').click
```

However, per your question, I tried to see if I could select by text. I found this works, but may be dependent on the labels being nested in a div.

```
@browser.label(:text => /Second Type/).click
```

The / around "Second Type" were due to some weird line breaks in the HTML, may work with just quotes.